# Transfering a File with a NetworkStream then rebuilding the file fails

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, networkstream

I am trying to send a file over a NetworkStream and rebuild it on the client side. I can get the data over correctly (i think) but when I use either a BinaryWriter or a FileStream object to recreate the file, the file is cut off in the beginning at the same point no matter what methodology I use.

```
  private void ReadandSaveFileFromServer(ref TcpClient clientATF,ref NetworkStream currentStream, string locationToSave)
    {
        int fileSize = 0;
        string fileName = "";

        fileName = ReadStringFromServer(ref clientATF,ref currentStream);
        fileSize = ReadIntFromServer(ref clientATF,ref currentStream);

        byte[] fileSent = new byte[fileSize];

        if (currentStream.CanRead && clientATF.Connected)
        {

            currentStream.Read(fileSent, 0, fileSent.Length);
            WriteToConsole("Log Recieved");

        }
        else
        {
            WriteToConsole("Log Transfer Failed");
        }

        FileStream fileToCreate = new FileStream(locationToSave + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
        fileToCreate.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fileToCreate.Write(fileSent, 0, fileSent.Length);
        fileToCreate.Close();

        //binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(locationToSave + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create));
        //binWriter.Write(fileSent);
        //binWriter.Close();

    }
```

When I step through and check fileName and fileSize, they are correct. The byte[] is also fully populated. Any clue as to what I can do next?

Thanks in advance...

Sean

EDIT!!!:

So I figured out what is happening. When I read a string and then the Int from stream, the byte array is 256 indices long. So my read for string is taking in the int, which then will clobber the other areas. Need to figure this out...

Comment: You'll need to post your ReadStringFromServer and ReadIntFromServer methods if you want further help.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, you can use the convenience method [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) to write the data more simply. But I doubt that that's the problem.

You're assuming you can read *all* the data in a single call to Read. You're ignoring the return value. Don't do that - instead, read multiple times until either you've read everything you expect to, or you've reached the end of the stream. See [this article for more details](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html). If you're using .NET 4, there's a new [`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) method you may find useful.

(As an aside, your use of `ref` suggests that you don't understand what it really means. It's well worth making sure you understand [how arguments are passed in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).)

Comment: Would that explain why the beginning of the file is being cut off?

Comment: Also isnt passing the networkstream and the connection the proper way to use it since I dont want a "copy" to be made and all actions i take on the object will be reflected globally?

Comment: @Sean P: They're reference types. It's not going to start copying the data around. Please read the article I linked to, which goes into a lot of detail. But I'd expect the *end* of the file to effectively be cut off, not the start. If the start is being cut off, that suggests there's something wrong in the earlier read operations.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Jon Skeet's answer, your reading code should be:

```
int bytesRead;
int readPos = 0;
do
{
    bytesRead = currentStream.Read(fileSent, readPos, fileSent.Length);
    readPos += bytesRead;
} while (bytesRead > 0);
```

Comment: By `do { ... } until (bytesRead == 0)` Jim means `do { ... } while (bytesRead > 0)`. Unless someone added a do..until statement in C# when I wasn't looking.

Comment: @Tergiver: Thanks.  You're right.  My Pascal is showing (and it's been years since I wrote anything in Pascal) ... I'll fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a general solution for sending and receiving files over a network have you considered using a [C# network library](http://www.networkcomms.net/c-network-library/)? It has probably solved most of the issues you will come across when trying to do this.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers of this library.